# How can I correctly align text of varying size along the bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css, text

I'm primarily a back-end guy, so apologies if this is a silly question. If I've missed any information that I should provide, I'd be happy to oblige.

I have a small currency sign, and a larger number that I want to be aligned along the bottom of the div so that their bottom pixels are in line. Currently it looks like this.

[image: number]

Now (I believe) I have the div containing the elements in the right place.

[image: div]

But as you can see the text flows out of it.

The css for the div is as follows...

```
position: absolute;
left: 375px;
top: 15px;
width: 400px;
height: 70px;
```

And for each the currency and number elements respectively.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
color: #e64611;

position: absolute;
left: 15px;
bottom: 0px;
color: #e64611;
font-size: 50px;
```

Comment: I see that I've rather quickly received -1 votes and a close vote. Could I get feedback on how to improve this question, please?

Comment: You could make a demo with JSBin or similar. Whatever, check my answer, i made it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `position: absolute`.

Use the `position: relative` to make the currency in the middle of the value:

```
.currency {
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  top:-10px;
}

.value {
  font-size:41px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Maybe for you will be useful to check [some front-end article](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) about CSS positioning.

[Here is the demo.](http://jsbin.com/yahocetiba/edit?html,css,js,output)